# To list out duplicate filenames in a listing?

Tags: text-processing, shell-script, scripting, awk

```
bash-3.00$ cat f.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 mukesh   other        102 Nov  5 18:32 f1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 mukesh   other         19 Nov  5 18:32 f2.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 mukesh   other        204 Nov  5 18:32 f3.txt //DUPLICATE
-rw-r--r--   1 mukesh   other        204 Nov  6 18:32 f3.txt  //DUPLICATE
-rw-r--r--   1 mukesh   other        204 Nov  6 18:32 f100.txt
```

Lets say i have the above file-names listed in a file called f.txt.
I want to list out all the file-names which have a duplicate(**only file-name**),
display the duplicate file name and number of duplicates.

Eg : In the above list f3.txt has a duplicate and there are a total of 2 f3.txt filenames found.

Comment: What do you **want** to use?

Comment: I could use any standard utility like awk,loops etc or aything you suggest.I think I need to take out the last column using awk and keep comparing using a loop inside a loop(may be a while do loop) I am trying that....Hope it works....I would appreciate any valuable inputs

Comment: Sort and uniq are standard utilities, they're as likely to be there as awk.

Comment: Thanks, @kevin I hope that it would be..I will edit my question anyway.

Comment: BTW, as far as I know, no Unix will ever allow your listing to happen. The filenames in a directory must be unique, though the differences might be unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `awk`, here is a solution in it:

```
awk '{d[$9]++}END{for(f in d)if(d[f]>1)print d[f],f}' f.txt
```

If you have also files with space characters in their names, then some workaround is needed:

```
awk '{f=$9;for(i=10;i<=NF;i++)f=f" "$i;d[f]++}END{for(f in d)if(d[f]>1)print d[f],f}' f.txt
```

Note that the above workaround may fail, for example on handling symlinks. After all, parsing `ls` output is not a good idea. Would be better to generate your f.txt in some other way, if possible. (For example `find` or `stat`, where you have better control over the list format.)

Comment: Your workaround won't work on a file name containing two consecutive space characters. For this input, it would be better to use `substr($0,55)`.

Comment: Oops, I missed the essential in the concatenation: not appended the `$i`. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I'd missed that too. My bug report still stands though.

Comment: Ah, got you now. You mean it will consider “a_b” and “a__b” the same. Well, I supposed spaces will appear as “a\\_b” and “a\\_\\_b”, as in the default `ls` output. (Used underscores as whitespaces are not preserved in comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in pure `bash`, since your question clearly indicates that you have bash 3 available:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' 'No input!'
    exit 1
fi

while read -ra _file; do
    _file="${foo[*]:8}"

    for _file_name_already_known in "${_files[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${_file_name_already_known} == "${_file}" ]]; then
            for _file_name_already_printed in "${_already_printed[@]}"; do
                [[ ${_file_name_already_printed} == "${_file}" ]] && continue 3
            done
            printf '%s\n' "${_file}"
            _already_printed+=( "${_file}" )
        fi
    done

    _files+=( "${_file}" )
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./lsdups < f.txt
f3.txt
```

Run as `./lsdups < file`.

Bear in mind that `ls` output is not the best thing to use, however. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs goes over some reasons why you should not do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [uniq](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uniq.html) utility removes or lists duplicates. The input needs to be [sorted](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html). Since only the file name part is relevant, tell these utilities to ignore what's to the left of the file names.

```
sort -k 1.54 f.txt | uniq -s 54 -cd
```